# Copying files from a network location without a trace

Tags: networking, security, vpn, windows-explorer

If I copy files from my company server, through a VPN to my work laptop at home and save it on the hard drive, will this be detectable by my employer? If so, will subsequently copying the files from my hard drive to a usb stick be detectable by my employer? If both questions can be answered by 'yes', is there a way to copy files from the company server through a VPN to a usb stick without leaving a trace (maybe for the second step through an app such as Droid Over Wifi: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dmitril.droidoverwifi)?

I'm aware of possible confidentiality and copyright issues so you can leave such comments out of your answer.

Comment: If reading actions are logged, then you are logged. Try to steal the hdd from server after covering all cameras!

Comment: What OS is running on the company servers?

Comment: Windows Server I think

Comment: I'm voting for closing this question. I don't think StackExchange is a place for asking "how can I do things that law or my company doesn't allow me to do". The only valid answer to this question is "if you have a solid reason to have those documents available outside the corporate premises and network, present a business case to your manager to validate your request".

Answer (score 1):

(*Answering for Windows Server OS; if anyone knows about other OSes feel free to edit*)

If your company has explicitly installed software that monitors server file reads, the first step (copying to your work laptop) will be detected, subsequent actions on your laptop won't.
There is no way you can circumvent this.

If they have not installed any monitoring software, they won't know.

Answer (score 0):

If network share is *nix running Samba then I would guess by default the act of you logging in will be noted is the syslog or auth.log. [Samba can be configured to log all user activity](https://moiristo.wordpress.com/2009/08/10/samba-logging-user-activity/), so it's a possiblity.

Answer (score 0):

VPN will give statistics on amount of data transfer and uptime, so yes, it's most probable that if anyone monitors the VPN they will detect you.

Copying files to HDD is only obvious if you have special monitoring tools installed; otherwise any decent file manager can x-fer files without a Windows OS logging anything.

Comment: It's not that I don't want to be detected being logged in via VPN, it's just that I don't want them to detect me copying files (or better: which particular files) from their server to my laptop. Does this addition change your answer?

Comment: Check if there is any monitoring software installed on the server or your laptop. If it's not, there's not much for you to worry about. If there is, investigate ways to bypass it.

Comment: How can you find out if monitoring software has been installed on my laptop?

Comment: Check the running tasks and find out what each unknown one does. Some of these applications do not appear as tasks but those are quire rare and you can detect them by monitoring what new files appear on your PC, since they usually make detailed logs and screenshots.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. How could I forget to check the running tasks? How stupid of me! So I checked and (with the help of Google) I found nothing that makes me suspicious. However, at the bottom of the Taskmanager window, I saw a button "Display processes of all users" (or similar words, I don't use the English version of Windows 7), but it can only be clicked/unlocked with administrator rights. Could it be that the software/process I'm looking for is running with admin rights and that it consequently cannot be displayed for me because I don't have administrator rights?

Comment: You need access to that. A monitoring process will not run under your user usually. You need to somehow get some admin rights and see what's running in there. Do you use domains ? You could ask the admins to make you local admin.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot get access to admin rights so this path is blocked. Does the list with installed programs publish ALL programs on my laptop or is it possible (for system admins) to hide programs in this list? And the same question for software/programs on my C drive: is it possible to hide programs on my hard drive?